# Combining gkai with bkai?

Tags: chinese

I would like to input the following text

> 今有物，不知其数。三三数之，賸二；五五数之，賸三；七七数之，賸二。问：物几 何？答曰：二十三。

But for bkai, it appears as

```
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bkai}
   {今有物，不知其数。三三数之，賸二；五五数之，賸三；七七数之，賸二。问：物几 何？答曰：二十三。}
\end{CJK*}
```

> 今有物，不知其。三三数之，賸二；五五数之，賸三；七七数之，賸二。：物几 何？答曰：二十三。

Whereas for gkai,

```
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bkai}
   {今有物，不知其数。三三数之，賸二；五五数之，賸三；七七数之，賸二。问：物几 何？答曰：二十三。}
\end{CJK*}
```

> 今有物，不知其数。三三数之，二；五五数之，三；七七数之，二。问：物几 何？答曰：二十三。

How can I combine these characters while preserving the Kaiti font?

Comment: Use modern technique—ctex bundle—for typesetting Chinese. Don't use CJKutf8 package.

Comment: Tried ctex, but I would also want to keep the line spacing in CJKutf8 as well.

Comment: ctex also provides interface for setting line spacing.